# Homogenizing button heights for responsive displays (CSS)

Tags: css

I have two buttons in my template like so:

[image]

I'm trying to ensure they remain symmetrical in size (height and width) over smaller screens. Yet, as screen width decreases, this happens:

[image]

How do ensure the `Foo` button is the same height as the `Bar Foo Bar` button even over smaller screen sizes? Looking for the simplest, purely CSS-based solution.

My current CSS looks like this:

```
<style>


div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:95%; 
    max-width:400px; 
    padding:5px;
}

div.tab button {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    width:49.5%;

}

div.tab button:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;
    color:#fb8c00;
}

</style>

<div class="tab">
<a href="example.com"><button>Foo</button></a>
<a href="example.com"><button style="float:right;border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;color:#fb8c00;background-color:#fff3e0;"><b>Bar Foo Bar</b></button></a>
</div>
```

---

Using `display:flex` in `div.tab` results in this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `display: flex`:

```css
div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;  /*here*/
}

div.tab button {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  width: 49.5%;
}

div.tab button:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;
  color: #fb8c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button>Foo</button>
  <button style="float:right;border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;color:#fb8c00;background-color:#fff3e0;"><b>Bar Foo Bar</b></button>
</div>
```

Giving that you are using links as child elements, the solution is `display-table`:

```css
div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table;
}

div.tab a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.tab a button {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

div.tab button:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;
  color: #fb8c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#/">
    <button>Foo</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#/">
    <button style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa726;color:#fb8c00;background-color:#fff3e0;"><b>Bar Foo Bar</b></button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange. Which browser are you using? Here is a fiddle for easier responsive check https://jsfiddle.net/s6ouw3ju/

Comment: Intriguing. My buttons are wrapped in `<a href="">` tags. The moment I remove them, it works fine (the way you intend it to) - otherwise not. Moreover, setting `display:flex` seems to have removed the breathing space between the buttons.

Comment: I think `display: flex` will only work if the buttons will be direct children of element `.tab`. You might want to try out `display: table` or `display: grid`. I'll try to come up with some examples. With regards to the space, it can be retrieved back by adjusting the width of the button.

Comment: Tried `display: table` and `display:grid`. It seems `display:flex` comes closest to working as per my requirements, but then like you said, it needs the buttons to be direct children, which they can't be because of the `<a href>` tag.

Comment: @HassanBaig please check this one ->> https://jsfiddle.net/s6ouw3ju/3/. I've used `display: table` example, tried with `display: grid` also, but the problem is same as with `display: flex`;

Comment: Yes this'll do. Do include it in the answer as well.